# How should it work to NOT match a set of patterns while parsing?

Tags: regex, parsing

I am putting together a parser generator / PEG system, and am stuck on the NOT situation. Basically, you can have rules like this:

```
everything_char_except_x = not x
```

You can get more complicated and say:

```
everything_except_x_or_y = not(x | y)
```

Then, x and y can themselves be complex rules, not just the letter x or y.

```
grammar = 8 everything_except_x_or_y 8
everything_except_x_or_y = not(x | y)
x = a | b | c
a = 1 | 2 | 3
b = 100 | 200 | 300
c = 5000 | 6000
y = x+ 4 x+
```

Something complicated.

The question is, how do you then parse such a statement? How do you skip over everything that doesn't match?

I know in regex-land, you have `/[xy]+[^xy]+[xy]+/`, with the `[^xy]` meaning NOT match. I don't really know how this works under the hood, but in my slighly more complex (albeit contrived) example, you want to match any character, followed by anything except these sequences with 1, 2, or 3 in it, or 100, 200, 300, etc. Kind of hard to imagine, but given we *don't* match that, say we have `898`, where `9` is not in `x` or `y`. Then when parsing, we see `index:1 == 9`, which is not x or y, so **move ahead 1 character** while parsing.

But this seems cumbersome/slow, moving ahead 1 character at a time. Can we not move ahead many characters in one swoop somehow? Or must we always proceed 1 character at a time in this situation?

Sorry if it's a little fuzzy of a question, but I'm trying to implement NOT matching, and not quite sure how it should work.

The reason I get confused is because, you might check like `b` which is 3 characters ahead, so if we find we have not matched `100` let's say, can we not skip ahead 3 characters instead of 1? Then this would mean, can we not skip ahead *as far as the longest match*? It seems like that assumption would break, but that's what I'm getting at.

*Me thinking out loud...*

`85007060008`, we would go:

- `8` matches, move ahead 1
- `1` doesn't match, continue
- `2` doesn't match, continue
- `3` doesn't match, continue
- `100` doesn't match, continue
- `200` doesn't match, continue
- `300` doesn't match, continue
- `5000` doesn't match, continue
- `6000` doesn't match, continue
- *move ahead just 1?*
- `1` doesn't match, continue
- `2` doesn't match, continue
- `3` doesn't match, continue
- `100` doesn't match, continue
- `200` doesn't match, continue
- `300` doesn't match, continue
- `5000` doesn't match, continue
- `6000` doesn't match, continue
- *move ahead just 1?*
- ...
- 6000 does match, okay string is invalid.

Comment: In a r.e., "not" of a character set is the complement of input chars. In a parser, as far as I have seen, "not" only applies to the terminal alphabet. This is easy to compute, of course. But, you could define "not(x | y | ...)" as the expression "( a1 | a2 | ...)" where "ai" is a non-terminal symbol in the grammar, and where "ai" cannot be "x" or "y" or "z" in the non-terminal alphabet. Or, you could define it as the transitive closure of unfolding the non-terminal "x" into a finite set of terminals.  I would do a survey of the popular parser generators and see how it is defined.

Comment: If `x` and `y` represent complex, self contained regex, then to use them in a superset sequence like `not( x | y)` requires isolating the atomic pieces from each other. To do that you can define `x = (some x)` or within the complex statement `not( (x) | (y) )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The (usual) PEG `!` operator, or at least the one which was defined by Bryan Ford in his [thesis on Packrat Parsing](https://bford.info/pub/lang/thesis.pdf)), is really a negative lookahead operator, analogous to the `(?!...)` operator in many regex libraries. Similarly, PEG has an `&` operator, which is a positive lookahead similar to the PCRE `(?=...)` operator. I think these are different from the negation operator you are imagining.

**Lookahead assertions do not consume any input.** However, they do succeed or fail, depending on whether the immediately following input text matches the provided pattern. Like all PEG primitives, they succeed or fail at a specified input point, so a successful lookahead could be said to match the empty string starting at a specific position, although it's easier to think of it as matching the position itself.

#### Digression: Regex negative character classes vs. negative lookahead assertions

That's a completely different concept from a regex character class. A regex character class always attempts to match a single character, which is consumed on success. The character class simply defines a set of matchable characters; the `[^...]` form of the character class uses the inverse of the set instead. There are a finite number of possible characters; the inverse of any set of characters is easily computable. So there's no magic needed for the implementation.

Thus, these two regexes do different things (neither of which is particularly useful; it's just a simple example):

```
/[^a]./
/(?!a)./
```

The first one matches any character other than `a` followed by any character. So it will match `ba` and `bb` but will not match `ab` (first character is `a`) or `b` (not followed by another character).

The second one first matches at the current input point if the next character is not an `a`, and then matches any character (still at the current input point). So it will match `b` but will not match `a`.

Crucially, the negative lookahead assertion subpattern can be arbitrarily long. Negative character classes can only match a single character. That makes negative lookahead significantly more powerful (and also more expensive to implement).

For example, suppose you want to match a sequence of characters which ends with the first instance of "END".  This can be done without a negative lookahead assertion, but it's extremely clumsy:

```
/[^E]*E+([^EN][^E]*E+)*N([^D][^E]*E+([^EN][^E]*E+)*N)*D/
```

But if you have a negative lookahead assertion, it's much easer, possibly even natural:

```
/((?!END).)*END/
```

If that looks mysterious (which is possible, since it includes a lot of punctuation), read `(?!END).` as "any character (`.`) which is not the first character in the sequence "END" (`(?!END)`).

The above example happens to check the predicate at every character position, but that's because the pattern matched after the predicate succeeds is `.`, which matches (any) single character, and the sequence of { assertion / match any character } is explicitly repeated. That's a simple example, but much more complex uses of lookahead are possible (and common). For example, you might want to match a comma-separated list of either simple entries or quoted entries, terminating at an entry which starts with the sequence `status`. (Such a pattern could be used to skip over uninteresting fields in a CSV.) That could be written as:

```
/((?!status:)([^"\n]*|("[^"]*")+),)*/
```

In that example, the string `Status:` is only checked at the beginning of an entry, so that entries which happen to include that sequence internally will not cause the pattern to terminate.

#### Returning to PEG

Parsing expression grammars, as [defined by Bryan Ford (2004)](https://bford.info/pub/lang/peg.pdf), effectively generalise this concept to arbitrary grammars, not limited to character-by-character matching. [See Note 1 for the precise definition, which actually comes from Ford's thesis where the exposition is a bit clearer.] According to Ford, the fact that PEGs allow character-by-character matching is useful because it lifts the need to use two different parsing techniques, one for tokenisation and another for syntax. But lookahead assertions make it relatively easy to match some interesting languages which are not even context-free. As an example, Ford's thesis shows how to write a PEG to match `{anbncn}`, a common example of a non-context-free language:

```
L → C END_OF_INPUT
A → a A b / ε
B → b B c / ε
C → (& A !b) a* B
```

`A` matches sequences with equal-length subsequences of `a` and `b`s, while `B` does the same for `b`s and `c`s. `C` effectively overlaps the `b`s at the end of an `A` with the same `b`s at the beginning of a `B`. The positive lookahead assertion `(& A !b)` succeeds if it is followed by an `A` followed by anything other than a `b`. Then `a*` is used to actually match the `a`s, and the `B` is matched against whatever follows, which is by then known to start with a sequence of `b`s of the same length as the sequence of `a`s. Thus, `C` only matches a sequence where the three subsequences have the same length, something which cannot be done by a context-free grammar.

#### How is this implemented?

That's the point of Bryan Ford's thesis, so reading it would be a good start. But the basic idea is simple enough: Every time a partial parse is attempted at some input point, the result is cached. If the same parse is attempted again at the same position, the cache result is returned immediately. (That's why Ford calls it "packrat parsing"; the packrat never discards anything, in case it will be useful again in some hypothetical future.)

The lookahead parses are cached like any other parse, with the detail that the result is cached *before* backtracking the parser to ignore the match (if necessary). So if the same pattern appears both in the lookahead target and a matching construct, the lookahead will also put the result into the cache and when the parser returns to that input point it will be able to move directly to the end of the pattern.

If I'm reading your question correctly, that's what you are asking, and if so, the answer is basically, "yes": it's not that the parser skips to the end of the longest match; it skips to the end of the previously computed match, whatever that might be. It can do that because all choices in a PEG pattern are ordered, and the parser never attempts another option once a match for that alternative has been found. That's quite different from the LR(1) parsing algorithm, which explores all alternatives in parallel, up to the point at which it has to reduce a production. Or the GLL/GLR algorithms, which also explore all alternatives in parallel so that they can return a forest of all possible parses for an input (or the only parse, if there is only one, regardless of how it was discovered). In fact, the basis for the "General" parsing algorithms was Chart-Parsing, which, like PEG parsing, keeps all possible subparses as long as they could still be relevant. (Since there is not a deterministic match order for context-free grammars, the parse may take super-linear time. But with practical grammars, it usually doesn't.)

The packrat strategy mostly means that each parser state is only entered once at each input position, and since there are a finite number of parser states, the entire parse can be done in linear time. To make it practical, some optimisations are required, but it turns out that with a little effort, you can produce a reasonably fast parser.

#### Notes

1. The lookahead operators are defined on page 67 of Ford's thesis, as follows:

   - An “and-followed-by” matcher has the form `&r`, where `r` is a unary rule. This matcher implements syntactic predicates: it causes the rule `r` to be invoked at the appropriate position in the sequence, and if it succeeds, the input position is backed up to the position before `r` was invoked, acting as if `r` had not consumed any input text. If `r` fails, then the sequence as a whole fails.
   - A “not-followed-by” matcher has the form `!r`, where `r` is a unary rule, and implements the negative form of syntactic predicate: if `r` succeeds, then the sequence as a whole fails; but if `r` fails, then the matcher succeeds without consuming any input text, and parsing of the sequence is allowed to continue.
     The use of "syntactic predicated" (as opposed to "semantic predicate") is due to Terrance Parr, and can be found in his 1994 paper, *Adding Semantic and Syntactic Predicates To LL(k): pred-LL(k)*.